# Jquery ajax call inside a then function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

So I need two ajax calls to get all the data. I am using `jQuery`'s ajax call to achieve that. But then I am a bit confused at the execution order. Here is my problematic code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/api/data",
dataType: "json"
}).then(function (data) {
   console.log("I am the first")//correct
}).then(function () {
   //second ajax
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/lifecyclephase",
    dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (data) {
       console.log("I am the second")//third
    })
 }).then(function () {
     console.log("I am the third")//second
 })
```

The output is

```
I am the first
I am the third
I am the second
```

Should not the `then`wait for the second `ajax` to finish its job before proceeding?

The correct one:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/api/data",
  dataType: "json"
}).then(function (data) {
  console.log("I am the first")
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/lifecyclephase",
    dataType: "json"
  }).then(function () {
    console.log("I am the second")
  }).then(function(){
    console.log("I am the third")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the problematic code, you are simply missing a `return`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/data",
    dataType: "json"
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log("I am the first");
}).then(function () {
    return $.ajax({
    ^^^^^^
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/lifecyclephase",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log("I am the second");
    });
}).then(function () {
    console.log("I am the third");
});
```

Without the `return`, there's nothing to inform the outer promise chain of the inner promise's exitence, hence the outer chain does not wait for the inner promise to settle before proceeding to the third stage.

Answer (score 1):

The "second" `$.ajax` is *initialized* within the second `.then`, but that `$.ajax` isn't *chained* with anything else - the interpreter initializes the request and that's it, so when the end of the second `.then` is reached, the *next* `.then` (the `third`) executes immediately.

Try `return`ing the second Promise instead - a subsequent `.then` will only wait for a `Promise` to resolve if that `Promise` is returned by the previous `.then`:

```
.then(function (data) {
   console.log("I am the first")//correct
})
.then(function () {
  //second ajax
  return $.ajax({
  // ...
```